# Can Bluetooth headphones be powered solely by 3.5mm audio jack?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, power, music, headphones

Is that possible for Bluetooth headphones to be powered solely by the 3.5mm audio jack? Especially if it runs out of juice? I am using [Outdoor Tech OT1400 Bluetooth headphones](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EUSMS8K) and just wondering if I can prolong my music-listening experience this way.

Comment: Well, if by “powered” you mean that you switch music input to analog audio, then yes, that’s the general idea.

Comment: No; Bluetooth cannot be powered over a 3.5mm audio cable....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

During periods of silence there is no current going through the audio cable. Even during periods of heavy sound, it's only around 2 volts. Not nearly enough to charge the battery and keep a consistent connection.

Answer (score 0):

This is a decent question, but to my knowledge 3.5mm audio connectors do not supply enough power to actual charge the battery of the headphones themselves.  All power going through a standard 3.5mm connector is strictly connected to creating audio; and that is a fairly low amount of power. Devices that do use 3.5mm connections for charging—like iPod Shuffles and such—usually have a third band on their 3.5mm connector to accommodate charger level power coming through.